# Exit 5 year locked investment, is verbal promise from bank enough?

Tags: fixed-income, maturity

I have 3 year locked fixed-income investment, I talked  with financial advisor and I was not able to take decision how to redirect it immediately so we agreed to meet in about a week. I met her as agreed, but surprisingly receptionist told me we did not schedule appointment. Advisor respected the verbal agreement and agreed to talked me. I told her to put money on 3 month locked plan instead, yet next day I got a letter of bank saying the 3 year plan was reactivated and I have 10 day to reverse it. Likely it was sent few days before the last meeting.

Could I rely on oral promise from the advisor or

- it is better to inform bank in writing?
- Or may be even registered letter?
- Or call the number they provided on the notice of renewal?

The low interest barely justifies the registered letter , but at the least I can cache or reinvest my money any time I need. Large Canadian Bank (QC).

Comment: I hoped to be able call on Saturday, as letter permit, so I do not have disrupt work or lunch, yet prerecorded voice tells me the office is closed until Monday

Comment: I don't trust anything unless it's in writing.

Comment: "We agreed to meet in about a week." That doesn't mean the advisor is sitting around waiting for you to walk in at an unspecified time. This isn't really question about money. Even if you *had* made an appointment, that wouldn't necessarily affect the terms of the investment. Likely, the advisor simply realized that you had a 10-day grace period to change your mind if you didn't want to go ahead with the 3-year renewal.

Comment: Yes, it is due 10 day period. Just check transaction list, she actually locked on 3 month money from the account. So I guess now as 10 day expired, nothing I can do with 5 year locked investment

Comment: As I believe advisor set specific day and time, this however now worries me less as finding means to exit contract imposed against my will

Answer (score 2):

The most likely explanation is, as you say, that the letter was automatically generated a day or two before you met with your advisor. Assuming that your advisor is competent, they will probably execute the instructions you gave them at the meeting. The letter said you had ten days to change the investment, and your advisor should be able to do it in that time.

To be on the safe side, since people have been known to forget things, I would call your advisor and tell them you got the letter, and check they are going to do what you decided. I would then follow it with a polite email, just saying that you both decided at your meeting on such-and-such a date to go with the three month plan. If that doesn't happen you can point to the email as evidence.

Don't panic about this. Even though the bank says you are 'locked in' to the decision, if an advisor makes a mistakes these decisions are in fact reversible, with the advisor paying any penalty.